# how to grant select only rows to user mysql using command line?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, rows, sql-grant

How am I able to grant a mysql user to only select rows in command line 
i.e GRANT SELECT X TO USER BOB ?

Have checked on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html, http://www.stackoverflow.com and others.

I have researched and there seems to be no conclusive answer.

I know it's a one-liner but after all I have tried, no dice.

Comment: I think you can use Views for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate please, I have tried something like this: GRANT SELECT .* TO 'bob'@'%';  I have tried other variations of this but with no luck.

Comment: Well, create a view of the limited data set and then grant bob access to that (untested).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the for all the table or

```
  GRANT SELECT ON your_db_name.* TO ''bob'@'%';
```

for a single table

```
  GRANT SELECT ON your_db_name.yor_table_name TO ''bob'@'%';
```

Comment: This would only select rows correct. My understanding is that your_db_name.* represents the database  name and * represents the table is this correct ?

Comment: yes .. the sample provided should grant select for all tables in "your_db:name" database ..  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: Yes, but only for rows in the table, sorry Im just abit confused.